# How to execute any .exe by using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, exe

I know that I can start an exe by doing:

```
start "" /b filename.exe
```

But that requires me to know the name of filename.exe, how could I do that for any general file ending with .exe? I tried the obvious wildcard implementation:

```
start "" /b *.exe
```

Windows, however, gives me an error saying it cannot find "*.exe" file.

Comment: What purpose would this be used for?

Comment: Executing one exe in a certain folder after it being extracted by a previous part of my script. (there will be only one exe in the folder, always)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you plan to run inside a batch file you can do in this way:

```
for %%i in (*.exe) do start "" /b "%%i"
```

if you want to skip a particular file to be executed:

```
for %%i in (*.exe) do if not "%%~nxi" == "blabla.exe" start "" /b "%%i"
```

if is necessary to check also the subfolders add the /r parameter:

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do start "" /b "%%i"
```

Comment: Actually, your answer was the only one that worked, since the other ones received an error in a folder with spaces (e.g. Doccuments and settings), thanks! Do you know if there's any way to add an "except"?(something like `for /r %%i in (*.exe) do start "" /b "%%i" except blabla.exe`)

Comment: try in this way

`for /r %%i in (*.exe) do if not "%%~nxi" == "blabla.exe" start "" /b "%%i"`

Answer (score 4):

From cmd run this to the folder that has all the `exe` you wish to run:

```
for %x in (*.exe) do ( start "" /b  "%x" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Hoep it helps

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "*.exe"') do (
    start %%a
)
```

You should first use dir command to find all exe files, and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

In a bat file add this line

```
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%G IN ('dir /A-D /-C ^| find ".exe"') DO start "" /b %%G
```

This execute every .exe file in your current directory. same as

```
*.exe
```

would have done if * were supported on batch.

If you want to execute it directly from a command line window, just do

```
FOR /F "tokens=4" %G IN ('dir /A-D /-C ^| find ".exe"') DO start "" /b %G
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Windows cannot find '167936', any ideas why?

Comment: it fails 1) in some date/time formats 2) if the file name has spaces

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame their codes for space issue. You should know how to use double quotation marks.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s *.exe') do (
    start "" "%%a"
)
```

Comment: I don't. And I still gave a +1 since it **half** worked. I just gave the best answer the selected one, I don't know why you are being so bitter about it.